# Wrong global.asax.cs path then debug in aspnet MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have done a project ASP.NET MVC 5 and I cloned this project to new one to add new features. In new project I add a breakpoint in global.asax.cs but when I debug it does not hit this breakpoint and I investigate it load the global.asax of old project. I cleaned bin and obj folder and rebuild even though delete the global.asax and create new one but it still not work.

Please help me explain why it load the global.asax of old project.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you encountered warning `The source code is different from the original version` on `global.asax.cs` breakpoint? Additionally you can check `Web` section inside Project Properties, examine the path of project URL, since `global.asax` file content executed first before debugging attached to running project.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto. You save my life. I changed the path url of project in Web section and it work well.